# Improper integral - check convergence

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Does the following improper integral converge ?

$$\int _0^{\frac{1}{2}}\:\cfrac{1}{\sin\left(x\right)\ln\left(x\right)}dx$$

I have tried to compare it to some known improper integrals but with no luck.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: this integral does not converge in the given interval

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $0<\varepsilon<\dfrac12$. From the inequality
$$
0<\sin x < x, \qquad \varepsilon<x<\frac12,
$$ one gets
$$
\int_\varepsilon^{1/2}\frac{-1}{\sin x \ln x}dx\ge\int_\varepsilon^{1/2}\frac{-1}{x\ln x}dx=\left[-\ln(-\ln x)\frac{}{}\right]_\varepsilon^{1/2}=\ln(-\ln \varepsilon)-\ln(\ln 2)
$$ yielding the divergence of the given integral as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$.

Comment: $$\int\frac{dx}{x\log x}=\log\log x$$ Why did you write $\;\log(-\log x)\;?$

Comment: @DonAntonio If you differentiate $\ln(-\ln x)$ you find $\dfrac1{x \ln x}$. One may recall that $0<x<1/2$.

Comment: I know that, the question was why...but I can see why now: for $\;x\in(\epsilon,\,1/2)\;$, we get  $\;\log x<0\;$ ...Ok, thank you. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio You are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @OlivierOloa

Comment: One question, isn't the limit of the integral suppose to be ln(1\2) and ln($\epsilon) $ ? @OlivierOloa

Comment: @Liad I've edited my first answer. Please tell me if it is still OK for you. Thanks.

Comment: Same question , I think the boundaries of the integral changes to ln(1/2) and ln$\epsilon $ after you integrate $\dfrac{1}{xln(x)}$ or am I missing something ? @OlivierOloa

Comment: Do you agree that $\left[\ln(-\ln x)\frac{}{}\right]_\varepsilon^{1/2}=-\ln(-\ln \varepsilon)+\ln(\ln 2)$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42969/discussion-between-liad-and-olivier-oloa).